# Why does returning a generic object show expected type parameter `T`, found struct `Vec`?

Tags: rust

I defined a function for postgresql pagination query like this:

```
pub fn fav_music_query<T>() -> Paginated<T> {
    use crate::model::diesel::rhythm::rhythm_schema::favorites::dsl::*;
    let connection = config::establish_music_connection();
    let query = favorites.filter(like_status.eq(1)).paginate(1).per_page(10);
    let query_result = query.load_and_count_pages::<Favorites>(&connection).unwrap();
    let page_result = Paginated{
        query: query_result.0,
        page: 1,
        per_page: 10,
        is_sub_query: false
    };

    return page_result;
}
```

when I use this code to invoke the function:

```
let dashboards = fav_music_query::<Vec<Favorites>>();
```

it shows this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/service/home/home_service.rs:18:12
   |
6  | pub fn fav_music_query<T>() -> Paginated<T> {
   |                        -       ------------ expected `Paginated<T>` because of return type
   |                        |
   |                        this type parameter
...
18 |     return page_result;
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found struct `Vec`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Paginated<T>`
              found struct `Paginated<Vec<Favorites>>`
```

what should I do to fix it? `Vec<>` not a T generic type?

Comment: Why is your function generic? You seem to always return `Vec<Favorites>`, and not use `T` at all.

Comment: When a function is generic over a type, it means that the **caller** gets to choose the type to use for `T`. That means that the caller can invoke, say, `fav_music_query::<u32>()` and have a right to expect `Vec<u32>`. Since your code always returns `Vec<Favorites>`, that can't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vec<?>` would be a valid option for `T`, but the issue is that it always attempts to return a `Vec<Favorites>` regardless of if the requested `T` is a `Vec` or not.
It is complaining because the function signature declares that it returns a generic, but the function implementation always attempts to return the same type.

```rust
// For example, according to the function signature I should be able to do this
let bar: Foo = fav_music_query<Foo>();
```

Now what I assume you want to do is have the function return a generic `Paginated` result. That isn't too difficult to do, we just need to replace the hard coded type with our generic and tweak the signature to match the result of `load_and_count_pages()` when we request our generic `T` from it. That being said, you will probably run into some errors with `load_and_count_pages` having bounds on the generic `T` which you will have to apply to the function signature `fav_music_query<T: SomeBounds + OtherBounds>()`.

```rust
// Tweak the signature to follow expected result of load_and_count_pages
pub fn fav_music_query<T>() -> Paginated<Vec<T>> {
    use crate::model::diesel::rhythm::rhythm_schema::favorites::dsl::*;
    let connection = config::establish_music_connection();
    let query = favorites.filter(like_status.eq(1)).paginate(1).per_page(10);

    // Change Faborites to T so the generic is used instead of a hardcoded type
    let query_result = query.load_and_count_pages::<T>(&connection).unwrap();
    let page_result = Paginated{
        query: query_result.0,
        page: 1,
        per_page: 10,
        is_sub_query: false
    };

    return page_result;
}
```

Alternatively, if you only want `Paginated<Vec<Favorites>>`, you could just remove the generic entirely and it should work just fine.

```rust
pub fn fav_music_query() -> Paginated<Vec<Favorites>> { ... }
```